Error with use features_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(PATH_Result) : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
I have an error when i use this command :
features_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(PATH_Result)

Error :
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o153.parquet. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
 ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 842, LAPTOP-4N2SL32T, executor driver):
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
 ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
 ...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
 at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
 ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Driver stacktrace:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
 ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
 ...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
 at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:86) ... 20 more


My context is :

I use a Jupyter notebook
PySpark version: 3.0.1
Java : JDK11
Python : 3.8

I initialize my Spark Session correctly :
import findspark
findspark.init()

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\anaconda3\envs\spark_env\Lib\site-packages\pyspark"

import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\anaconda3\envs\spark_env\python"
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = r"C:\Users\xxxxx\anaconda3\envs\spark_env\python"

# Initialisation de Spark pour le traitement local.
spark = (SparkSession
             .builder
             .appName('app')
             .master('local') # Utilise tous les cœurs disponibles
             .config("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", 'true')
             .config("spark.python.worker.timeout", "3000") # Test
             .config("spark.python.worker.reuse", "true") # Test
             .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") # Test
             .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true")
             .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true")
             .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
             .config("spark.executor.cores", 2)
             .config("spark.driver.memory", "8g")
             .config("spark.driver.cores", 2)
             .config("spark.worker.memory", "1g")
             .config("spark.network.timeout", "800s")
             .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "60s")
             .getOrCreate()
)

And my code is :
# Définition des chemins.
PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH_Data = PATH+'/data/Test1'
PATH_Result = PATH+'/data/Results'
print('PATH:        '+\
      PATH+'\nPATH_Data:   '+\
      PATH_Data+'\nPATH_Result: '+PATH_Result)

sc = spark.sparkContext
# Chargement des images en local en tant que fichiers binaires.
images = spark.read.format("binaryFile") \
  .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.jpg") \
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
  .load(PATH_Data)

# Extraction du label de l'image à partir du chemin.
images = images.withColumn('label', element_at(split(images['path'], '/'),-2))
# Chargement et préparation de MobileNetV2 pour le transfert d'apprentissage.
model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet',
                    include_top=True,
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
new_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                  outputs=model.layers[-2].output)

# Diffusion des poids.
brodcast_weights = sc.broadcast(new_model.get_weights())

# Renvoie un modèle MobileNetV2 avec la dernière couche supprimée et les poids diffusés.
def model_fn():
    """
    Returns a MobileNetV2 model with top layer removed 
    and broadcasted pretrained weights.
    """
    model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet',
                        include_top=True,
                        input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    new_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                  outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
    new_model.set_weights(brodcast_weights.value)
    return new_model

# Prétraite les images pour le modèle de prédiction.
def preprocess(content):
    """
    Preprocesses raw image bytes for prediction.
    """
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content)).resize([224, 224])
    arr = img_to_array(img)
    return preprocess_input(arr)

# Extrait un vecteur de caractéristiques pour chaque image de la série.
def featurize_series(model, content_series):
    """
    Featurize a pd.Series of raw images using the input model.
    :return: a pd.Series of image features
    """
    input = np.stack(content_series.map(preprocess))
    preds = model.predict(input)
    # For some layers, output features will be multi-dimensional tensors.
    # We flatten the feature tensors to vectors for easier storage in Spark DataFrames.
    output = [p.flatten() for p in preds]
    return pd.Series(output)

# Pandas UDF pour featuriser des images en lot avec Spark.
@pandas_udf('array<float>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER)
def featurize_udf(content_series_iter):
    '''
    This method is a Scalar Iterator pandas UDF wrapping our featurization function.
    The decorator specifies that this returns a Spark DataFrame column of type ArrayType(FloatType).

    :param content_series_iter: This argument is an iterator over batches of data, where each batch
                              is a pandas Series of image data.
    '''
    # With Scalar Iterator pandas UDFs, we can load the model once and then re-use it
    # for multiple data batches.  This amortizes the overhead of loading big models.
    model = model_fn()
    for content_series in content_series_iter:
        yield featurize_series(model, content_series)

# Transformation d'un DataFrame d'images en un DataFrame qui contient les caractéristiques (features) extraites des images.
features_df = images.repartition(5).select(col("path"),
                                            col("label"),
                                            featurize_udf("content").alias("features")
                                            )
# Ecriture en Parquet.
features_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(PATH_Result)

Thanks a lot for your help :) !
I try to adjust spark session parameters (driver memory, worker memory, ...), i check that i can write in PATH_Results, etc... but i don't understand what is the problem.
When i launch my command "features_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(PATH_Result)", i see that a temorary repository is created in PATH_Results but it is removed when the error appears.
I search since 1 week...
Thanks a lot :)

Looks like java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt() is the root cause. Some mismatch of expected data format inside PATH_Data vs the reality perhaps?

Hi @kashyap, in my repository "Data" I have lots of subdirectories with jpg images inside. When i use .parquet to write path and label is ok but it's seems to be featurize_udf("content").alias("features") that doesn't work but i don't understand why. How I can adapt my code to debug an input data problem ? Thans a lot.
